# Flutter video player caption adjustment

Tags: flutter, dart, video-player

Is it possible to move the caption (subtitle) of flutter's video to different position? I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/video_player and was wondering if it's possible to customize where the subtitle will appear. Also is it possible to toggle the caption on and off while playing the video?

Answer (score 0):

just use `Stack` widget and you will be fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).